# Rails Integration Test - filling out form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

Why would not this work?

Some people are talking about `webrat`, but isn't Rails supposed to handle form signup directly?

The below test does not trigger the `User#Create` action, and I wonder why. Nothing seem to happen.

```
test "should not sign up more than 5 users" do
  get "signup"
  assert_response :success
  assert_difference('User.count',5) do
    for i in 0..10 do
      puts "Signup user"
      post_via_redirect "/signup",
                        :first_name => "Petter",
                        :last_name => "Smart",
                        :email => "petter.smart<%=i%>@prayalot.com",
                        :password => '123456',
                        :password_confirmation => '123456'
      assert_equal '/sentmail', path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, lots of problems:

```
post_via_redirect "/signup",
```

Since you mentioned you have #create, this line should post to #create. "/signup" is for #new.

```
:email => "petter.smart<%=i%>@prayalot.com",
```

The interpolation should be `"petter.smart#{i}@prayalot.com"`

```
assert_equal '/sentmail', path
```

I don't know how is your logic, but if your code doesn't allow more than 5 signups per day, the users after 5 should not get mail sent, instead they may see a notice for "no more today", at least they should be treated differently from first 5.

Comment: Awsome! Thank You! Posting to the right controller helped a lot! Strange that many examples refer to the /signup path which normally contains the signup form. I also had to wrap the parameters inside a :user object. So in practice I don't test the form at all... but just the create method. Don't know how to test the form itself, but its good for now. I will post the working code below. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm! :-) Thanks to Billy Chan for his advice.

```
test "should not sign up more than 10 users from same IP" do
    get "signup"
    assert_response :success
    assert_difference('User.count',10) do
        for i in 1..10 do
            post "users", :user => {
            :first_name => "Petter",
            :last_name => "Smart",
            :email =>  "petter.smart#{i}@prayalot.com",
            :password => '123456',
            :password_confirmation => '123456'}
            assert_redirected_to sentmail_path
        end

        for i in 11..20 do
            post "users", :user => {
            :first_name => "Petter",
            :last_name => "Smart",
            :email =>  "petter.smart#{i}@prayalot.com",
            :password => '123456',
            :password_confirmation => '123456'}
            assert_redirected_to error_path
        end
    end
end
```